# Free OpenVPN client with per-app split tunneling

Tags: gratis, windows-10, vpn

Pretty much what the title and tags say. GUI preferred, text configs fine. May agree to an alternative to OpenVPN as long as it has free servers and resulting ping of less than say 300 ms. (This excludes Tor.)

Tried several free OpenVPN clients, no luck yet. The closest thing to per-app split tunneling I could get was an advice to manually set up the default gateways of my virtual adapters. I'm running Virtualbox already, so the setup is complicated as it is.